# get upper triangle of eigen::selfadjointView<Lower>()

Tags: c++, eigen

I have this which works fine:

```
MatrixXf Sig(p,p);
Sig.selfadjointView<Lower>().rankUpdate(xSub.adjoint());
```

Now, i need to also get the upper triangular 
part of `Sig`. [This](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=109729&sid=b7152c9f2bb0531d3b568275e856aa6b) answer seems to suggest 
to do

```
Sig.triangularView<StrictUpper>()=Sig.adjoint().triangularView<StrictUpper>();
```

But doing that causes mayhem --or as the compiler calls it:

```
DetMCD_1.cpp: In function ‘float CStep(const MatrixXf&, Eigen::VectorXi&, const int&, const int&)’:
DetMCD_1.cpp:263:21: error: ‘StrictUpper’ was not declared in this scope
DetMCD_1.cpp:263:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>::triangularView()’
DetMCD_1.cpp:263:34: note: candidates are:
/home/kaveh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:248:79: note: template<unsigned int Mode> typename Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::TriangularViewReturnType<Mode>::Type Eigen::MatrixBase::triangularView() [with unsigned int Mode = Mode, Derived = Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>, typename Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::TriangularViewReturnType<Mode>::Type = <type error>]
/home/kaveh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:249:84: note: template<unsigned int Mode> typename Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::ConstTriangularViewReturnType<Mode>::Type Eigen::MatrixBase::triangularView() const [with unsigned int Mode = Mode, Derived = Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>, typename Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::ConstTriangularViewReturnType<Mode>::Type = <type error>]
DetMCD_1.cpp:263:78: error: no matching function for call to ‘Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001> >::triangularView() const’
DetMCD_1.cpp:263:78: note: candidates are:
/home/kaveh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:248:79: note: template<unsigned int Mode> typename Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::TriangularViewReturnType<Mode>::Type Eigen::MatrixBase::triangularView() [with unsigned int Mode = Mode, Derived = Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001> >, typename Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::TriangularViewReturnType<Mode>::Type = <type error>]
/home/kaveh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:249:84: note: template<unsigned int Mode> typename Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::ConstTriangularViewReturnType<Mode>::Type Eigen::MatrixBase::triangularView() const [with unsigned int Mode = Mode, Derived = Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001> >, typename Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::ConstTriangularViewReturnType<Mode>::Type = <type error>]
make: *** [DetMCD_1.o] Error 1
```

My question is this: given that i have 
the lower triangular part of `Sig`, how 
to convince eigen to return me the full 
matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is typo, it's StrictlyUpper, and not StrictUpper. See the respective [doc](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a90150a6deb18826cee5ece716663358a). The following two lines are equivalent:

Long version:

```
M.triangularView<StrictlyUpper>()=M.adjoint().triangularView<StrictlyUpper>();
```

Short version:

```
M.triangularView<StrictlyUpper>()=M.adjoint();
```

Please, also not that in most cases you do not need to explicitly compute the upper triangular part.